# How to RegEx in Codemirror to match paragraph first and last words?

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I'm using Codemirror to build a texteditor with some nice feats such as syntax highlighting, using language modes in [simple mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html), and trying to write a couple of regex to match the first and last words of a paragraph. For instance, in:

```
One
is the first one
of all the numbers

Two is
the second
```

The first regex (first word in paragraph) should match `One` and `Two`, and the second one (last word in paragraph) should match `numbers` and `second`.

I've been trying different expressions but couldn't finally find the right one. This is the closest I got, but still obviously not right:

```
/[^\r\n]+[a-zA-Z]\s/
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested using Notepad++ and rubular.com**

*Find what:* `^([A-Z]\w+)(\s\w+)?((\r?\n|\r)([a-z]+\s)+)+(\w+)$`

*Replace with:* `\1\n\6`

**Input**

```
One
is the first one
of all the numbers

Two is
the second

Three is
the third

Four is
the fourth
of all the numbers
```

**Output**

```
One
numbers

Two
second

Three
third

Four
numbers
```

**Rubular**

[image]

Comment: This regular expression is not working in Codemirror. Please note the question is specific to CodeMirror, not about Regex in general.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been open for a while, but wanted to share that for CodeMirror regex, the usual '^' cannot be used for start of line/string match. However, { regex: ..., sol: true } works fine.
E.g. in defineSimpleMode()
"sol" stands for "start of line"